# User resize an image in iPhone app

Tags: ipad, uiimageview, xcode5, image-resizing

I have an app I would like to have the user to be able to resize an image in. How would I go about this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean resize the imageview (as in pinch zoom?) or resize the actual image?

Comment: Resize the actual image

Answer (score 0):

Actually scaling an image can be easily done like this:

```
- (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)input to:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);

    [input drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

You can create your own UI to let the user choose sizes to scale to

Comment: Can you grab a corner and drag smaller and larger with this

Comment: No, you would have to design a custom interface to do this.